# Catalina reopens app windows upon login despite turning it off

Tags: macos, bluetooth, catalina, login, login-items

I noticed this issue as soon as I updated to macOS 10.15(Catalina). The OS opens every previously opened windows even when the `Reopen windows when logging back in` is unticked.

[image]

Another bug I noticed was the same problem occurring with bluetooth. The weird part is, if you turned on the bluetooth while working and then turned it off before shutting down, it'll be turned on when you'll log back in.

Is this an update bug for macOS Catalina or has anyone experienced this before. And if so, what are the ways it can be resolved by?

**Other Helpful Information:**

1. The apps that are reopening are just the ones I used last before logging out. In fact and I double checked none of them are present in my Login items.
2. I usually close the apps with CMD+Q which quits the whole app and not just an instance.
3. I have just one user account and no guest accounts

Comment: I have opened the same thread on [Apple Discussions(Not solved)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250968787)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have you login profile set to launch those apps no matter what. For example I want Mail.app and Calendar.app to launch even if I have reopen windows unchecked. Look in Preferences under Users and Groups

Comment: Apps that are reopening are just the ones I used last before logging out. In fact and I double checked none of them are present in my Login items.